# React rendering view from array in state

Tags: reactjs

I have trying about not been able to figure out the reason. I have a state variable which gets updated in constructor

```
renderUpcomingReminders(){
    const upComingReminders = _.map(this.state.upComingReminders,(reminder, key) =>{
      if(!reminder.edit){
        return(<Row >
          <Col sm={12}>
            <div className="products" >
              <h4 className="content"> <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"> </span> {typeof reminder !== 'undefined'?reminder.message: null}
                <span className="badge badge-default">{typeof reminder !== 'undefined'?moment(reminder.scheduled_datetime).format('MMMM DD at hh:mm a'): '-'}</span></h4>
              <div className="pull-right">
                <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={()=>{this.editReminder(key)}}>Edit</Button>
                <Button bsStyle="danger" >Remove</Button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>);
      }else {
        return (<Row key={key.toString()}>
          <Col sm={12}>
            Edit here.
          </Col>
        </Row>);
      }
    });
    console.log(112);
    return upComingReminders;
  }
```

So this function is to render the reminders according to the edit flag.

```
<Col sm={12}><h4><a className="heading">Upcoming Reminders</a></h4></Col>
                {()=>{this.renderUpcomingReminders()}}
```

This is how I am calling the function to render the result. Now problem is that the function is not logging the value in console `.log` function.

I am confused with React's iteration and conditional rendering.

Comment: `{()=>{this.renderUpcomingReminders()}}` You aren't calling the function here, you're creating another function that calls `renderUpcomingReminders`..

So I think what you want is `{this.renderUpcomingReminders()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `{()=>{this.renderUpcomingReminders()}}` with `{this.renderUpcomingReminders().bind(this)}`